# Mahler Symphony 5: Notes say Db but recording says D

Tags: piano, orchestra, pitch, hearing

I've been practising **Mahler's 5th Symphony** for quite a while now on the piano (the transcription/arrangement by Otto Singer II) and I recently realized that I was playing a **D** instead of a **D-flat**, which is what the notes actually suggest:

[image]

This is a passage from the third movement (the Scherzo). When playing it again with a **D-flat** it sounded so *off* compared to what I had heard countless times listening to this recording that I had to go back and check:

[Bernstein - Mahler 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EJn43FEmjo&t=31m08s)

No matter how many times I replay that part I keep hearing a regular **D**. The same goes for [this one conducted by Barenboim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxS5zeeA53I&t=32m54s). I did read [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/51480/brandenburg-concerto-no-5-in-d-why-do-some-recordings-seem-to-be-in-c-sharp) about why some recordings seem to be in a different key, but that is not the case with this question. It's literally just this one note during this passage.

Am I hearing this correctly? - *I don't have perfect pitch but this seems pretty clear to me* - Am I wrong? Are both my ears and my piano so far out of tune? I have a strong feeling that I'm missing something pretty simple here, but what?

I also thought that it might just be a transcription error so I looked into the orchestra score but that one also says **D-flat**:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first edition of the score (Peters, 1904) has D naturals.

[image]
The Peters "revised edition" (also dated 1904, but issued in 1905) has D flats.

The Peters Urtext edition (1964) has gone back to D naturals.

"Revised" doesn't always mean "better"!

All three editions are on IMSLP.

Answer (score 2):

The individual parts on IMSLP are from a different edition, and have accidentals turning those notes into D♮'s:

[image]

(From the [Flute I part](http://ks.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/4/4b/IMSLP43529-PMLP08063-Mahler-Sym5.Flute.pdf), p. 9.)

Which version is "right" I can't say, but at least you know that you're not going crazy.